# Create virtual user for Sitecore solution - Impersonation purpose

Tags: sitecore, virtual, impersonation, sitecore7

I really need some help, but let me explain first what I have to do.

I have a `Sitecore` super-user, which has the `Impersonation` role. This user is supposed to be able to impersonate other users (all of them are on `extranet` domain), having the profile information and the roles of the original user.

The main thing about this super-user is that he should be able to impersonate another and change settings or other aspects of the impersonated account.

I tried different approaches but I can't seem to be able to figure this out. Creating virtual users is the way I am thinking, but can't succeed.

Just to mention, each User from this solution has a custom Profile template assigned to them that must be kept after creating the virtual user.

Also, I have some quick questions. Does anyone know where are this virtual users located after creation? Or for how much time are these stored? Do they need to be deleted somehow?

**Many thanks to anyone that could help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

Apparently the solution for was using Virtual Users actually, like in the following:

```
var virtualUser = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(emailAddress, true);

SetBaseProfile();
SaveUserRoles();

// login the virtual user
AuthenticationManager.Login(virtualUser);
```

In order to check if the active user is virtual or not, I had to use:

```
AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser().RuntimeSetting.isVirtual;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher` class. I'm not sure if it would do the trick, but you can try:

```cs
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher.Enter(someOtherUser)
```

and then

```cs
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher.Exit()
```

or

```cs
using (UserSwitcher switcher = new UserSwitcher(...))
{
    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

To check if you are in `UserSwitcher` mode, use:

```cs
User impersonatedUser = UserSwitcher.CurrentValue;
```

If the value of `impersonatedUser` is null, it means that you're not in the `UserSwitcher` mode.

Comment: In this case, would I be able to check if I am impersonating or not? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: @MariusPopa you can use `UserSwitcher.CurrentValue` property. See updated answer.

Comment: Cool. I will give it a try and come back with an answer. Thanks.

Comment: So...apparently the `UserSwitcher` could not be used in this case, because this would mean that I have the possibility to only make some operations on that specific user, but not actually log in with it as normally. So I still have to stick to the virtual user idea.